# Where do cancelled downloads go in Ubuntu software center?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, uninstall

When you cancel a download in Ubuntu software center, where exactly do they go?

Are they deleted or do we need to manually delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install any packages using the command `apt-get install` or using any GUI package manager such as Ubuntu Software Center. The process is the following:

- Download the package .deb into the `/var/cache/apt/archives`
- Install the .deb resolving the dependencies that was already installed in the `/var/cache/apt/archives`

So now for you question of what happens for canceled installation.

> When you cancel a download in Ubuntu software center, where exactly do
>   they go?

Easily there is a directory located under the above path which means `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial` responsible for holding those discontinued installation.

You can easily check it yourself. Try to install some package and cancel it then go to the directory above to find the part which was already downloaded to the time of cancel.

The second part:

> Are they deleted or do we need to manually delete them?

In fact those packages needed to remove manually.

you can use the regular rm

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb
```

Also if you don't care about keeping the packages (.deb) already installed and which is found under `/var/cache/apt/archives` you can use the command

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

This will remove the .deb packages from `/var/cache/apt/archives` and from `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial`

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu software center downloads the packages to `/var/cache/apt/archives`. As far as I know, if you cancelled the downloads they will be removed automatically but I can not confirm this. If it does not, you can always remove them using the `rm -r` command.